# Correlate start/stop dates and sum their duration

Tags: sql, sql-server

UPDATE: At the bottom I added expected output with the table I had envisioned

My goal is two correlate downtime events to show causation of one event and the downtime it caused.

I have an overall schema of:

```
DECLARE @EquipmentDownTime TABLE
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
Equipment varchar(5),
Time DATETIME,
StartStop NVARCHAR(15)
)
```

so a record looks like this:

```
 1, Motor, '18/8/2017 12:00:00', Stop 
 2, Motor, '18/8/2017 12:10:00', Start
```

I'm currently using a matching pairs table function to sum the total duration of downtime between user entered date ranged but I want to expand the functionality to say how long an event caused another based on those durations.

What I'm trying to do is correlate when another piece of equipment "Stop" is in between the record above and then determine it's total time of being. Using the Sample data below:

```
INSERT INTO @EquipmentDownTime (Equipment, [Time], StartStop)
VALUES
  ('Motor', '20170812 12:00:00', 'Stop'), --ID 1
  ('Valve', '20170812 12:05:00', 'Stop'), --ID 2
  ('Motor', '20170812 12:30:00', 'Start'), --ID 3
  ('Valve', '20170812 13:05:00', 'Start'), --ID 4
  ('Motor', '20170812 14:00:00', 'Stop'), --ID 5
  ('Valve', '20170812 14:05:00', 'Stop'), --ID 6
  ('Motor', '20170812 15:30:00', 'Start'), --ID 7
  ('Valve', '20170812 15:05:00', 'Start'); --ID 8
```

In this case I would say ID 1 Caused 1 hour of downtime for ID 2 since it's stop fell in between 1 and 3 which are a Stop/Start Pair.

I imagine the end result would look something like this:

```
 DECLARE @Causation TABLE
(
ID INT                     IDENTITY(1,1),
CauationEquipment          varchar(5),
CauationEquipmentShutdown  DATETIME,
AffectedEquipment          varchar(5),
AffectedEquipmentShutdown  DATETIME,
DurationOfAffectedEquip    INT
)
```

Records Result (Causation Id and Affected, comes from Identity Id in @EquipmentDowntime Table):

```
 1, Motor, '20170812 12:00:00', Valve, '20170812 12:05:00', 60
 2, Motor, '20170812 14:00:00', Valve, '20170812 14:05:00', 60
```

The piece I am missing here is effectively linking the correlation I have thought to use a while loop going through all the downtime events and grab the stop and its next start and store it in temp tables but it is getting messy.

SQL Server 2014

Comment: Do you mean to say that, "...Caused 1 hour of downtime for ID 2 ..." ID 2, not ID 3?

Comment: @KatherineElizabethLightsey yes sorry will edit

Comment: Could you have Downtimes of 24(or more) hours? You also have your Duratiuon as an INT. Do you only want to the nearest hour? If something went down at 13:00 and was up again at 13:05 what should be displayed? What bout 13:00 and 13:45?

Comment: @Larnu It is possible, if that is the case you would see a record of 'start' the next day. I only ever log pairs per equipment.

Comment: @Larnu Right now I return the downtime as a DATEDIFF of the two dates and sum values.

Comment: This is the current function I use to sum the pairs:
https://pastebin.com/BzwPJ61f

Comment: @Matt, that doesn't really answer by question. `DATEDIFF` for example. can take several parameters. Do you want `DATEDIFF(SECOND...`,`DATEDIFF(MINUTE...`,`DATEDIFF(HOUR...`, other?

Comment: @Larnu Minutes is what I'd like

Comment: My early career was as a machine design engineer (CMfgE, Machine Design), so this is an interesting question. I am approaching initially using the LEAD/LAG functionality introduced in SQL 2012, but it becomes difficult as you add more equipment. I think at some point you need a hierarchy to determine if there is a causal event in a tree. Otherwise you might have one piece of equipment stop and not know if you need to go back one, two, twenty, or fifty stop values prior to see what caused the stoppage.

Comment: @KatherineElizabethLightsey `LEAD`/`LAG` is the right way to go, but you can split the equipments by using `PARTITION BY`.

Comment: Do you have equipment that is unrelated to one another in the table? For example Motor1 and Motor2. If Motor1 stops and something goes wrong with Valve2 they are unrelated events?

Comment: @Larnu, I think you are correct, but Chris Albert brings up the point of concern. I like your answer as a starting point, but I think a hierarchy is required.

Comment: @KatherineElizabethLightsey At this point in time, I can't see a good reason for a hierarchy. As I said in the answer, however, it runs under the assumption that a downtime is only applicable to one piece of equipment, and there aren't multiple logs. If one fault can create multiple downtimes, then they either need to be logged separately, or they need to be recorded in a different table, which you can built a relationship on.Either way, that still doesn't build a hierarchy.

Comment: @all In this table we only record one active downtime at a time. Any downtime events halts the logging of others. Until that equipment is restored.

Comment: I agree that a heirarchy or tree is going to be needed to do anything with the Causation table.  If the system needs to know that ID 2 (`Valve Stop`) is caused by ID 1 (`Motor Start`), how does the table know that ID 5 (`Motor Stop`) isn't caused by ID 4 (`Valve Start`)?  How does the table know that `'Motor'` causes `'Valve'` problems?  What happens when `'O2 Sensor'`, `'Oil Pressure'`, etc. are added to the mix?

Comment: @BaconBits for my case I only ever care about 1 piece of equipment being down and thats the 'valve' and the causation is any stop before the 'valve' stop. Le'ts say we had Motor 1-5. If Motor 1 is currently in 'Stop' - then nothing else but the 'valve' is logged if it's stop

Comment: @BaconBits Long term we want to hook up hardware to make the reason tree possible. At the moment we only know from timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're on SQL Server 2012+, and that a single Downtime will only have 2 entries (one for the stop and one for the start):

```
WITH Downtime AS (
    SELECT *,
           LEAD([Time]) OVER (PARTITION BY Equipment ORDER BY [Time] ASC) AS NextStatus
    FROM @EquipmentDownTime)
SELECT ID,
       Equipment,
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE,[Time],NextStatus) AS Duration
FROM Downtime
WHERE StartStop = 'Stop';
```

Comment: So this will give me downtime duration of the "motor" going down but how can I effectively link that incident to the "valve" shut down time.

Comment: I updated the sample and expected output let me know what you think.

Comment: We don't have details of where your Causation ID is coming from. Also, we don't have an ID for your equipment, you only supplied a `varchar` (hence why i changed your table variable to use a `varchar`, not an `int`). Achieving your expected results with the data supplied is **impossible**. You need to either supply more data (and the relevant DDL), or provide different expected results that can be derived from the data we have.

Comment: The causation Id would just be the Identity Id from the main table and the causation is determined by the time stamp, since the valve stop took place in between the the motor start stop we would know the motor caused the valve to go down.

So the ID's of 1 and 5 in the result would come directly from the @EquipmentDownTime table.

Comment: Instead of using the ID, I could use the NVARHCAR as well.

Comment: So, out of interest, why does the solution above not give you the results you expect (apart from `CausationID`, which we have no data on).

Comment: I think it's got me halfway there, I'm going to update the question to make it more clear. I appreciate your help on this as well.

Comment: I updated the sample data as well as the needed output. Let me know if that makes more sense, The example I gave was confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I expanded upon what Larnu provided and this matches the output I expected in my question:

```
DECLARE @EquipmentDownTime TABLE
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
Equipment varchar(5),
Time DATETIME,
StartStop NVARCHAR(15)
)

INSERT INTO @EquipmentDownTime (Equipment, [Time], StartStop)
VALUES
  ('Motor', '20170812 12:00:00', 'Stop'), --ID 1
  ('Valve', '20170812 12:05:00', 'Stop'), --ID 2
  ('Motor', '20170812 12:30:00', 'Start'), --ID 3
  ('Valve', '20170812 13:05:00', 'Start'), --ID 4
  ('Motor', '20170812 14:00:00', 'Stop'), --ID 5
  ('Valve', '20170812 14:05:00', 'Stop'), --ID 6 --
  ('Motor', '20170812 14:30:00', 'Start'), --ID 7
  ('Valve', '20170812 15:05:00', 'Start'); --ID 8

 ;WITH 
    Causation AS (
        SELECT ID,
        LAG(Equipment) OVER (ORDER BY [Time] ASC) AS LastEquipment,
        LAG([Time]) OVER (ORDER BY [Time] ASC) AS PrevEquipDownTime
        FROM @EquipmentDownTime
        ),
    Downtime AS (
        SELECT *,
        (LEAD([Time]) OVER (PARTITION BY Equipment ORDER BY [Time] ASC)) AS NextStatus
        FROM @EquipmentDownTime
        )
SELECT Downtime.ID,
       LastEquipment AS [CauationEquipment],
       PrevEquipDownTime AS [CauationEquipmentShutdown],
       Equipment   AS [Affected Equipment],
       Time AS [AffectedEquipmentShutdown],
       NextStatus,
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE,[Time],NextStatus) AS Duration
FROM Downtime 
JOIN Causation
ON   Downtime.ID = Causation.ID
WHERE StartStop = 'Stop'
AND Equipment = 'Valve'
```

Output:

```
2,  Motor,  2017-08-12 12:00:00.000,    Valve,  2017-08-12 12:05:00.000,    2017-08-12 13:05:00.000,    60
6,  Motor,  2017-08-12 14:00:00.000,    Valve,  2017-08-12 14:05:00.000,    2017-08-12 15:05:00.000,    60
```